# SQL select segment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table with x amount of rows. I would like to always divide x by 5 and select the 3rd group of records.

Let's say there are 100 records in the table:

```
100 / 5 = 20
```

the 3rd segment will be record 41 to 60.

How will I be able in SQL to calculate and select this 3rd segment only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NTILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx).

> Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups.

Example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM
(
    SELECT
        col1, col2, ..., coln,
        NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS groupno
    FROM yourtable
)
WHERE groupno = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfect use for the [`NTILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) ranking function.

Basically, you define your query inside a CTE and add an NTILE to your rows - a number going from 1 to n (the argument to `NTILE`). You order your rows by some column, and then you get the n groups of rows you're looking for, and you can operate on any one of those "groups" of data.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH SegmentedData AS
(
   SELECT  
      (list of your columns),
      GroupNo = NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumnOfYours)
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM SegmentedData
WHERE GroupNo = 3
```

Of course, you can also use an `UPDATE` statement after the CTE to update those rows.